# Issue with CTA Button

Tags: wordpress, mobile

When I access my website on a mobile device and click on the "Schedule a Free Consultation" button, it initially scrolls to a different section instead of taking me directly to the form. On the first click, it navigates to another section, and only on the second click does it properly redirect to the exact form. What could be causing this issue?

https://rklegaladvisors.com/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlnPO.jpg)

Comment: It's not clear from your question which section your mobile is wrongly scrolling to as it seems to work fine for me but I have noticed that the page has multiple `id` attributes of the same value. You cannot have more than one element with the same `id` so it's possible that this is what's causing the issue. There are 3 instances of `id="form"` (Please note: The reason I'm not answering this as an answer is because I am unable to reproduce the same issue, if you could provide more details or hopefully this gives an insight that others can explain better).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I made a screenshot for you https://prnt.sc/yjdVJ3P0MzLg, and I saw that you are using the same ID three times. Try deleting it and using it in only one place. Also, if you want to globally set it so that when you scroll, it doesn't touch the top section, you can use `scroll-padding-top: 150px;`.